# Smart Contract (SC) - Is it a Block itself?

Tags: ethereumj, ethereum-design

Is SC a block itself on the Ethereum Block chain or it's just a storage? I know SC has its own hash address, it's own data stored in State variables, but does it has nonce and gas limit?

Answer (score 1):

Contract is one of two types of the accounts on the ethereum network. The second type of account is EOA (Externally Owned Account) - the account owned by user.
Smart contract is not a block - in simple words block is a set of transactions. Nonce is a property of a block and gas limit is a property of transaction.

Basic features of smart contract accounts:

- has an ether balance,
- has associated code,
- code execution is triggered by transactions or messages (calls) received from other contracts.
- when executed - perform operations of arbitrary complexity (Turing completeness) - manipulate its own persistent storage, i.e., can have its own permanent state - can call other contracts
  -

You can read more about ethereum architecture here:
http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you like the answer, you can accept it, so I will earn some points ;)